# Edge not showing download option with PDF object?

Tags: object, pdf, embed, microsoft-edge

I have an PDF embedded in the page using the following code:

```
<object width="100%" height="800" type="application/pdf" data="/example.pdf" id="pdf_content">
            <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
```

Every browser shows an option to download the PDF when hovered.

Are there any parameters that can be added in order to show the save option?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it's unlikely because the interface is generally handled by whatever PDF plugin the browser uses, worst case you could add a download link above the embedded object